# Ruby Spreadsheet gem each do loop excluding last row

Tags: ruby, spreadsheet

I am trying to iterate through a spreadsheet using the spreadsheet gem in ruby.  I need to start on the 6th row due to a bunch of garbage on the first 5 rows, but can't seem to figure out how to skip the last row as it is blank

my code:

```
sheet.each 6  do |row|
  puts row
end
```

works great, but again puts a blank row at the end of the worksheet.  I've tried

```
sheet[6..-1].each do |row|
sheet.each[6..-1] do |row|
```

both throw errors.  I get the feeling there is a very elegant way of doing this that I just am not getting.

Comment: Are you referring to the [zdavatz/spreadsheet gem](https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet)?

Answer (score 0):

You were close, you need access the `rows` inside the sheet first

```
sheet.rows[6...-1].each do |row|
  puts row
end
```

*Also, one additional dot `.` within the Range used to exclude the end value.*

> Ranges constructed using `..` run from the beginning to the end inclusively. Those created using `...` exclude the end value.
>
> -- [Class: Range (Ruby 2_4_0)](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Range.html)